# Can I replace an if-statement with AND?

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

My prof once said, that if-statements are rather slow and should be avoided as much as possible. I'm making a game in OpenGL, where I need a lot of them.
In my tests replacing an if-statement with AND via short-circuiting worked, but is it faster?

```
bool doSomething();

int main()
{

  int randomNumber = std::rand() % 10;

  randomNumber == 5 && doSomething();

  return 0;
}

bool doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "function executed" << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

My intention is to use this inside the draw function of my renderer. My models are supposed to have flags, if a flag is true, a certain function should execute.

Comment: No, you have to check conditions, and branch somehow in your code.

Comment: No, current compilers are smart enough to optimize that away. In fact using if or && will probably yield the exact same bytecode.

Comment: "My prof once said, that if-statements are rather slow and should be avoided as much as possible." I think this quote has been extrapolated from the context. It's also strange for a teacher to say something like that without explaining why and how.
Anyway, use `if`s with no problem.

Comment: Just because the *code* doesn't have an `if` doesn't mean it the end result isn't the same--there's still a check happening. This smacks of premature optimization.

Comment: Do not overthink this. In C and in C++ there is ["As-if rule"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) what means that `if` or `and` result code most probably will be the same. Your professor was taking about very low optimization which should be ignored by beginner and intermediate developer (any code branch introduces overhead for CPU and in both cases you have branches). Advanced developer should use this only for time critical code.

Comment: Basically && invokes the same logic as if. There should be very little difference in performance. In many cases the compiler will try to find ways to avoid doing the conditional branch, which is the slow operation, but in other cases it can't find a way.

Comment: If the logic actually is conditional, then there isn't fundamentally anything that can be done about that. There are special cases where you can avoid branches that the obvious logic would have, but the compiler can implement them automatically for you. At any rate, we are talking about things that potentially waste literally *billionths* of a second. What your professor says is irrelevant, very out of date, and a distraction from the task of *learning to write code*. (You should probably not be getting taught in C++ anyway, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: So even inside a shader, where the code gets executed e.g. for every pixel, it wouldnt make a difference?

Comment: Executing `std::cout << "function executed" << std::endl;` takes several orders of magnitude more time than any potential savings from avoiding a given branch. Even then, the hardware itself tries to avoid the potential slowdown, using something called "branch prediction". Optimization on modern architectures has much more to do with managing and understanding caches.

Comment: `randomNumber == 5 && doSomething();` is unnecessarily obscure, don't do it.

Comment: @noergel1 shader is completely different thing. It doesn't follow standard on C++. Execution there governed by documentation for shader language. And it depends on which language and GPU arch you're using.

Comment: @PaulSanders because it is not a question that should be asked. Thinking about the issue is a distraction. Beginners - in every field, and almost by definition - do not always know what questions should be asked, where they should be focusing their attention.

Comment: Alright thank you all for your answers.
Just wanted to say, maybe newbies like me shouldn't concern too much with such little details, but just like I won't overthink using if-statements anymore, another person might see your guys' answers and come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not sure about that line of reasoning. How are they suppose to find out if a question "should be asked" or not? And what are the criteria for "a question that shouldn't be asked"?. If you mean a question to which you believe the answer should be "do not worry about that topic", then feel free to give your advice but that belief does not invalidate the question.

Comment: Thank you @François, that is a much more considered comment than mine was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments above that in almost all practical cases, it's OK to use `if`s as much as you need without hesitation.
I also agree that it is not an issue important for a beginner to waste energy on optimizing, and that using logical operators will likely to emit code similar to `if`s.

---

**However - there is a valid issue here related to branching in general, so those who are interested are welcome to read on**.

Modern CPUs use what we call [Instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining).
Without getting too deap into the technical details:
Within each CPU core there is a level of parallelism.
Each assembly instruction is composed of several stages, and while the current instruction is executed, the *next* instructions are prepared to a certain degree.
This is called instruction pipelining.
This concept is broken with any kind of branching in general, and conditionals (`if`s) in particular.
It's true that there is a mechanism of [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), but it works only to some extent.

So although in most cases `if`s are totally OK, there are cases it should be taken into account.
As always when it comes to optimizations, one should carefully profile.

Take the following piece of code as an example (similar things are common in image processing and other implementations):

```
unsigned char * pData = ...; // get data from somewhere
int dataSize = 100000000; // something big
bool cond = ...;    // initialize some condition for relevant for all data
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i, ++pData)
{
    if (cond)
    {
        *pData = 2; // imagine some small calculation
    }
    else
    {
        *pData = 3; // imagine some other small calculation
    }
}
```

It might be better to do it like this (even though it contains duplication which is evil from software engineering point of view):

```
if (cond)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i, ++pData)
    {
        *pData = 2; // imagine some small calculation
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i, ++pData)
    {
        *pData = 3; // imagine some other small calculation
    }
}
```

We still have an `if` but it's causing to branch potentially only once.

In certain [rare] cases (requires profiling as mentioned above) it will be more efficient to do even something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; ++i, ++pData)
{
    *pData = (2 * cond + 3 * (!cond));  
}
```

I know it's not common , but I encountered specific HW some years ago on which the cost of 2 multiplications and 1 addition with negation was less than the cost of branching (due to reset of instruction pipeline). Also this "trick" supports using different condition values for different parts of the data.

**Bottom line:** `if`s are usually OK, but it's good to be aware that sometimes there is a cost.

Answer (score 5):

> if-statements are rather slow and should be avoided as much as possible.

This is wrong and/or misleading. Most simplified statements about slowness of a program are wrong. There's probably something wrong with this answer too.

C++ statements don't have a speed that can be attributed to them. It's the speed of the compiled program that matters. And that consists of assembly language instructions; not of C++ statements.

What would probably be more correct is to say that branch instructions *can be* relatively slow (on modern, superscalar CPU architectures) (when the branch cannot be predicted well) (depending on what you are comparing to; there are many things that are much more expensive).

> ```
> randomNumber == 5 && doSomething();
> ```

An if-statement is often compiled into a program that uses a branch instruction. A short-circuiting logical-and operation is also often compiled into a program that uses a branch instruction. Replacing if-statement with a logical-and operator is not a magic bullet that makes the program faster.

If you were to compare the program produced by the logical-and and the corresponding program where it is replaced with `if (randomNumber == 5)`, you would find that the optimiser sees through your trick and produces the same assembly in both cases.

> My models are supposed to have flags, if a flag is true, a certain function should execute.

In order to avoid the branch, you must change the premise. Instead of iterating through a sequence of all models, checking flag, and conditionally calling a function, you could create a sequence of all models for which the function should be called, iterate that, and call the function unconditionally -> no branching. Is this alternative faster? There is certainly some overhead of maintaining the data structure and the branch predictor may have made this unnecessary. Only way to know for sure is to measure the program.

Comment: Addendum:  making a change to improve performance **MUST** be informed through profiling of optimized code.  Profile, profile, profile.  Otherwise those changes are baseless and may actually harm performance (but one doesn't know unless there is profiling), and almost certainly harms code legibility and maintainability.  Sounds crazy, but I've run into that in the real world, where a dev thought he was making the code better, and I profiled his changes and showed him his lovingly fine-tuned code was about x100 slower.

Comment: !!! But for OpenGL shaders, it's true that `if` should be avoided. It requires all the executing threads to wait until the condition is done, leading to waster of time on idleness

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov The question was about C++ and not about a shader language though :) Wouldn't a logical-and equally require all executing threads to wait in shader languages? I'm not an expert on GPU programming, but I would assume the reason for "if" being slow in CPU is similar to why it is slow on GPU (although lack of branch prediction and higher parallelisation presumably makes the effect more severe). In either case, it's the branch that you must avoid and it doesn't matter what high level construct produces that branch.

Comment: There's no short-circuiting in OpenGL shaders AFAIK, so this issue doesn't arise. And about the slow speed of conditions on GPU - it's because there are thousands of cores in a GPU, that it would be too expensive to provide each with separate branch predictors or other controller circuits. So instead many cores are grouped, where the whole group is led by a single controller / branch predictor, so if any core waits - the whole group waits idle as well.

Comment: [Here is godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/PTPxeYM55) proving that both alternatives are indeed translated to identical instructions.